# Numpy - reading array from CSV as [153, ] instead of [153, 394]

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a CSV file that has 153 rows and 394 columns. Up to now, I was able to read in the CSV file and remove the last three columns with:

```
all_data = np.genfromtxt('data.csv',delimiter=",",names=True)
test_data = all_data[::3]
test_data_x = all_data[:,:-3]
```

This had been working fine until today. As I ran it today this won't work and when I printed out all_data I got:

```
[(1,5,10...4),(2,7,16...3),...,(153,2,16...2)]
```

I printed out the shape of all_data I got back [153,]. I have tried np.reshape() but then I get:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

The only thing that has been updated is the csv that I was reading the data in - but its in the same format only with headers now. I'm not sure how to get numpy reading this CSV in correctly?

Comment: What does `print({len(row) for row in all_data})` return?

Comment: set([394]). From playing around with it, it seems to be names=True that is causing this to happen, as when I remove that I get a normal array.

Comment: With `names` it creates a structured array.  The columns are now `fields` defined by the `dtype`.  153 elements, 394 fields.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, there's a stray character in that new csv file that prevented some of your numbers from being interpreted as numbers. You might need to check each of the resulting tuples item-by-item, to find the offending bit of data.

Comment: I was just testing that out. Unfortunately no stray character - but I found that if I removed 'names=True' then it worked. I then just added skip_header = 1, but I would rather keep the headers in. The only issue with the headers I can think of is that they all have a space before each title. Would this cause the issue?